# Selenium how to get tooltip hover message when no attribute available

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

I'm trying to capture a tooltip hover message but don't have a title tag nor any attribute I can find to identify the text. It seems to be a button tag that has its attributes change when I hover over it to add the attribute "is-hover". But I don't know how to get the text that appears on the screen when that attribute is added when the mouse hovers over the button. I think it's using reactJS.

Any ideas?

```
    <div class="taxButton">
        <span class="calculateButton">
            <button tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" title=""
                    class="v-Button danger was-active is-hover tax-flag-banner tax-btn  TaxFlags flagStyle"
                    role="button">
                <i class="icon"></i>
                <span class="label">Tax</span>
            </button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

`html` button tag:

[image]

I've tried mouse hover and .getText() on the button and .getAttribute for title and is-hover. Nothing has worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The tooltip element was stored somewhere else in the DOM. I searched the DOM for the text of the hover message and found it. Then I simply had to make the mouse move to that button and then create the xpath to the tooltip element that was not "closed" and contained the text.